# MatterJS precompute final position

Tags: javascript, 2d, game-physics, matter.js

I am trying to create a simple 2D game where a ball is falling to the ground, influenced by some obstacles that will change the final position of the ball.

I am using MatterJS as a 2D physics engine but it is actually unpredictable, with the same parameters my ball is always at a different final position.

Is there a way to precompute the path the ball will have (instantly), save it into a variable and load it to get the exact same path whenever I need it? Or is there a way to predict the final position accurately?

Comment: That's an interesting question about determinism. I found this Rust-to-JS  physics engine that claims to be so. I don't anything about this but thought these two points could be helpful in the future for people trying to navigate these issues... Now I really feel like trying this Rapier thing in an old simple physics based game I made...

Comment: Related: [Outcome always different in matter.js physics engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210236/outcome-always-different-in-matter-js-physics-engine) and [In the plinko game written with the matter.js engine library, how to make the ball always fall into the pre-planned position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642529/in-the-plinko-game-written-with-the-matter-js-engine-library-how-to-make-the-ba#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to precompute instantly the path of the ball by calling manually `Matter.Engine.update(engine)` and storing the position of my ball for each frame.

Then i reset the position of my ball, set `ball.isStatic = true;` and move it manually at each frame:

```js
Matter.Events.on(engine, "afterUpdate", () => {
    if (positions.length > 0) {
        Matter.Body.setPosition(ball, positions.shift());
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. Could you please share full example code?

Comment: If you're using Matter.js headlessly, once you have the positions of all the bodies, you can totally drop the physics library and just work with your animation frontend. Also, `.shift()` is linear, and since this is hot loop code called many times per second leading to quadratic complexity, I'd reverse the `positions` once up front, and then use `pop()` rather than `.shift()` to keep your code linear.

Answer (score 1):

***Matter.js* is deterministic.** The only varying parameter is the deltas, the intervals between the ticks. The results will always be the same for a certain set of deltas.

However, its debug renderer, `Matter.Render`, synchronizes the ticking to the frame rate of the display, `window.requestAnimationFrame()`, by default, and this makes the deltas vary randomly every time you run the code.

You can make the time elapse manually with `Matter.Engine.update(engine, delta)`. Keep the ticking under *your control*, know your deltas, and the results will be consistent.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/820#issuecomment-595799394) from the author of the library supports the suggestion that the engine is deterministic, but [this comment on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/lc7q31/comment/glyvqui/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) claims the opposite. Do you have a citation or evidence for your claim here?

Comment: @ggorlen Yes. Firstly, I’ve read the source code of the engine, `Matter.Engine`, and found nothing even slightly random; it was just a bunch of mathematical calculations. Secondly, I’ve used Matter.js with manual steps (`Matter.Engine.update`) and it ended up with identical results and identical decimal digits every time I rerun the code. _The engine is completely deterministic. What is not is its debug renderer_, `Matter.Render`, which synchronizes the updates to the frame rate of the display (`window.requestAnimationFrame()`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for clarifying. That agrees with Liabru. Feel free to update your answer if you want and I'll delete the comment thread so it's more permanent.

Answer (score -1):

Once you are rendering matterjs in browser and need deterministic you have to keep `event.source.timing.lastDelta` the same.

You can achieve it by:

1. Always using the same `Engine` instance that you keep globally.
2. Configuring `_seed` and polyfiling trig functions:

   ```
   import trigf from 'trigfills';
   import * as MatterJS from 'matter-js';

   trigf.setmaths();
   MatterJS.Common._seed = 13579; // random value but always the same

   export default MatterJS;
   ```
3. Set option `isFixed: true`, while creating `Runner`

   ```
   Runner.create({
     isFixed: true,
   })
   ```