# How to land the peg in a predetermined multiplier in plinko just like stake.com?

Tags: javascript, next.js, pixi.js, matter.js

I am trying to make the final position of the ball land on a specific multiplier after bouncing off of the pins in plinko. I wanted to know how stake.com plinko animation lands on the specific multiplier after bouncing off the pins.

I am using matterjs for the physics engine but it comes as a random outcome.

Comment: Existing: [MatterJS precompute final position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847252/matterjs-precompute-final-position), [In the plinko game written with the matter.js engine library, how to make the ball always fall into the pre-planned position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75642529/in-the-plinko-game-written-with-the-matter-js-engine-library-how-to-make-the-ba), [GH issue #820](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/820), [GH issue #1190](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1190), [GH issue #1199](https://github.com/liabru/matter-js/issues/1199).